# How can I grow trees underground?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can trees grow without sunlight?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/8540/can-trees-grow-without-sunlight)

Ok, so I'm trying to plant this tree underground and it's surrounded by torches and directly under a 4x4 sky light. It's a normal sapling on 5 deep dirt. I've used like, 10 bonemeals on it and it isn't working.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Hello, CtK, and welcome to Arqade! Unfortunately, your question is quite vague - are you sure the tree has enough room? Trees can only grow if they have enough room to do so. Would it be possible to provide a screenshot of your situation?

Answer (score 14):

Trees need 7 blocks above them to grow, depending on sapling type. They also have a minimum horizontal requirement as well. Hollow out more space. If you use bonemeal and nothing happens, then you don't have enough space.

Comment: It's worth adding even more height, in my opinion, so you can get huge type trees. Also, a torch directly next to the sapling will provide sufficient light.

Comment: I should point out that sometimes if a tree can be nothing but big (because of tree farms or terrain) it takes more than one bonemeal to make it grow.

Comment: @JonathanDrain I personally like to keep the height low enough so big trees *can't* grow, because they're such a pain to harvest. It's personal preference, really.

Comment: I have had trees require significantly more than 10 bonemeal to grow if the growth area is highly constrained.

Comment: If you're building an indoor tree-farm and worried about tree height, why not build a balcony (into the wall, so as not to obstruct growing height) so you can walk straight onto the top of the tree from there?